# Mithilfe dessen / mit dessen Hilfe

Tags: pronoun

Was ist korrekt?

> Das ist das Handy, *mithilfe dessen* ich die Polizei gerufen habe, als ich einige Typen den Automaten habe brechen sehen.

> Das ist das Handy, *mit dessen Hilfe* ich die Polizei gerufen habe, als ich einige Typen den Automaten habe brechen sehen.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Beides ist richtig. Diese beiden Ausdrücke unterscheiden sich nur wenig.

- mithilfe dessen — eher für Gegenstände
- mit dessen Hilfe — eher für Personen

Es muss auch *aufbrechen* heißen, nicht *brechen*.